DESeq2 padj differ a lot from limma & edgeR analysis
i'm having some difficulties understanding differencies in padj calculation in DESeq2 respect to limma & edgeR. I'm using test data with 5 healthy samples and 5 disease sample. It is normal that p-value differ like that?
dds <- estimateSizeFactors(ddsTxi)
filtered_genes <- rowSums(counts(dds) >= 10) >= (ncol(dds) / 2)
dds_filtered <- dds[filtered_genes, ]
dds_filtered <- DESeq(dds_filtered)
res <- results(dds_filtered, contrast = c("group", "disease", "healthy"), lfcThreshold = 1, cooksCutoff = F)
res_filtered <- res[res$padj <= 0.05, ]
> res_filtered.df
                  baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue         padj
IGHV3-30         748.81639      12.520299 1.7518336  6.576138 4.828254e-11 
IGLV3-25         787.73323      11.327897 1.4383719  7.180269 6.957447e-13 
IGHV3-49         240.35750      10.881116 1.0428510  9.475099 2.665089e-21 
IGLV2-18         240.34083      10.880756 1.4121829  6.996796 2.618818e-12 
IGKV1-6          471.52213      10.838236 0.9403616 10.462184 1.288512e-25 
IGLV3-19        3394.63949      10.677759 0.7953877 12.167348 4.639110e-34 
IGKV1D-33       1289.91551      10.524039 0.7194581 13.237795 5.308483e-40 
IGLV3-1         1748.26674      10.470238 0.5973499 15.853754 1.324292e-56 
IGLV10-54        180.39686      10.466864 1.6913951  5.597074 2.179993e-08 
IGHV3-53         467.31180      10.466634 0.8807581 10.748279 6.037750e-27 
MMP1           70806.12090      10.453865 0.6319851 14.959001 1.360532e-50 

same samples analyzed with limma and edgeR report similar LOG2FC but totally different padj
group <- factor(targets$group)
design <- model.matrix(~0 + group)
colnames(design) <- levels(group)
v.DEGList.filtered.norm <- voom(myDGEList.filtered.norm, design, plot = TRUE)
fit <- lmFit(v.DEGList.filtered.norm, design)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(infection = disease - healthy,levels=design)
fits <- contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
ebFit <- eBayes(fits)
myTopHits <- topTable(ebFit, adjust ="BH", coef=1, number=40000, sort.by="logFC")
                   logFC      AveExpr          t      P.Value    adj.P.Val           
MMP1           10.811364  6.656104979  13.344542 1.850951e-08 1.244090e-06  
IGLC3          10.288004  3.492650878   7.518879 7.952738e-06 7.604019e-05  
IGKV1D-33      10.229349  1.116511588   9.331072 8.822073e-07 1.565046e-05  
IGKV2D-28      10.082185  0.898462482   9.523328 7.124072e-07 1.354091e-05  
IGLV3-25       10.010268  0.242702175   6.908813 1.813279e-05 1.431296e-04  
IGLV3-1        10.005929  1.748391611  11.842773 6.883173e-08 2.791843e-06  
IGKV1-5         9.925822  3.363145736  13.850135 1.224740e-08 1.007992e-06 
IGHV1-3         9.886930  0.447926148   6.261069 4.583851e-05 2.964023e-04  
IGLV3-19        9.842028  2.184963159   6.958590 1.692390e-05 1.361195e-04  
IGHV3-21        9.795755  1.417188571   9.024589 1.249408e-06 1.973411e-05  
IGLV2-8         9.773432  2.060931959  13.844952 1.229851e-08 1.007992e-06  
IGKV1D-39       9.681327  2.583496010   9.671441 6.056265e-07 1.202065e-05  
IGHV4-34        9.662238  1.369932576   6.696774 2.441521e-05 1.812382e-04  
IGLV3-21        9.641737  3.087064678   5.233231 2.246810e-04 1.073818e-03  
IGKV1-6         9.638834 -0.112334051   7.940951 4.615981e-06 5.060817e-05  
IGLV2-23        9.624652  3.125414661   9.009834 1.270807e-06 1.999166e-05  

So the question is, is it normal to have this different output for padj?

It looks like the two results you are showing are from two different models, each with different assumptions. So, while the log foldchange is similar between the two, the test statistic is computed in a different way and the p-value is different. Why would you expect two different models to have identical inference?

I'm kinda new to this, so working on the same raw data i was expecting to have similar results even if two different models were used. So it is normal to have different statistics?
I realized now that i have deleted padj on the first analysis but the concept it is still the same

Yeah you will definitely get different p-values with the two models. In practice I'll generally see lower p-values with the DEseq2 workflow. Make sure you record down the type of transformation / normalization used for your methods, but also in doing so you'll find out the assumptions used to explain your differences (e.g., TMM normalization). Aside from potentially different normalization, the model used in calculating logFC and p-value will differ. The manuals for both these packages are very helpful to read.

Either way, you'll want to generate some tables for the top genes up/down and volcano plots. You'll likely see some similar genes toward to the top which would be good, but look for some differences to see how each model might be handling more extreme observations (e.g., are p-values/fold-changes inflated for low average expression genes?). Make some mean-variance plots before and after your filtering step and see if your filtering genes step is too conservative/liberal or just right, see https://ucdavis-bioinformatics-training.github.io/2018-June-RNA-Seq-Workshop/thursday/DE.html
